# How to check JAVA_HOME environment variable under Cent OS 7

Tags: centos-7

The manual of Collabnet says that we have to setup JAVA_HOME environment variable.
How to check if this variable has been configured already?

```
1. Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, and point it to your Java 6 JRE
      home.  For example:

      export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default

      Test the variable:

      $ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
      java version "1.6.0_20"
      Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
      Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: `env | grep JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I to check if JAVA_HOME has been configured already?

There are many ways to do this.

In a `bash` shell you can use any of the following commands:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME

printf $JAVA_HOME

env | grep JAVA_HOME

printenv | grep JAVA_HOME
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.